# Noise in measurement

Tags: operational-amplifier, battery-charging, charger, voltage-measurement, ripple

I'm having a problem when I measure a voltage from a lead battery. I provide my circuit so you can understand better whats happening.

For example I measure a 24 V battery, goes to a resistor divider and then to an operational amplifier (+ terminal). On the other side (- terminal) there is a  stable voltage through a TL431. The output of this goes to my PIC.

If I connect a variable supply instead of a battery and "mimic" how it would be, all function perfectly. The problems appear when I connect a real battery. I think that the problem is the ripple because while I'm measuring the battery the voltage does not exceed the reference voltage in the negative terminal of the AO but it activates the input of the PIC, therefore the output of the AO.

Summing up, what its the best option? An LC filter? An active filter with an AO? An AO as integrator?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: According to your schematics, you have swapped positive and negative from the battery. Is that the case, or did you just make a mistake in the drawing?

Comment: Also, your schematic does not include any values of any of the resistors. And what is the 12 pin "BAT" thing in the bottom right corner?

Comment: A battery shouldn't have any ripple.

Comment: Simplest causes, i think, are absence of decoupling capacitor for PIC (should be ceramic, electrolytic doesn't count), and absense of capacitors in the negative feedback loop of OPAMP. It should work as low pass filter with lowest acceptable frequency. Looks like long wires causes instability and oscillation.

Comment: @Vladimir there is a capacitor in the pic between GND and VCC... In the negative feedback of the opamp i think that you refer to put capacitors between R5 and GND, R7, and GND, R9 and GND. Im correct? But im pretty sure that will not solve my problem, because my problem comes in the positive feedback of the OPAMP...

Comment: @JRE Im measuring the battery voltage while im charging the battery so i think thats it generating ripple, also the long cables connecting the battery

Comment: @Klas-Kenny thanks, the battery its wrong on the schematic. The "BAT" pin are jumpers, so when you connect for example the first jumper you have RBAT1 and RBAT as resistor divider, when you connect the second jumper RBAT2 and RBAT... So i create a different resistor divider for different voltage batteries.

Comment: @samuelmattio:  You appear to be using linear regulators - no ripple.

Comment: Capacitors across digital ICs power lines should be ceramic (typ. 0,1 uF) because they have low ESR. On circuit shown there is polar cap, most likely it is electrolytic, which ESR is high. This advices can be found in datasheet.
Feedback caps for LP-filter should be placed between opamps output and negative input. They are neighbors for such purposes.
Could you clarify the need for opamps? Why not to connect battery to ADC via just voltage divider? This will improve both precision and input resistance and TL431 will not be needed.